# What is the correct vote-to-close option for this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

I saw [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955486/facebook-album-style-of-gallery), and I was wondering what the correct reason or option will be to choose to close this question, because it is both **off-topic** and **too-broad**.

Well, the question read:

> *Any library has the similar feature like Facebook album? I want to display all categories, click on category and display all photos in
>   that category. Any free jquery library is recommended?*.

Posted the question if the link gets broken.

Now this type of question comes under *too-broad* which says **There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.** and it is *off-topic* too which says **This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center - Asking for recommending library/plugin/software tools**.

What is the correct option to close this question?

Comment: As to the off/topic part, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ welcomes such questions (when properly stated), so migration would be an option.

Comment: @Mawg and we agree that the question that we are talking about is *not even close to properly stated* to match the [quality guidelines of SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), right?

Comment: Absolutely! (+1) Did I not  make that clear? However, we at SR do welcome such questions (when they follow the guidelines)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main thing that the questioner seems to be asking for is a jQuery library. The questioner wants a library that will let him/her click on a category to display pictures in that category. So I don't necessarily think s/he is asking for code to how to do it. S/he wants a library that will do all of it for him/her.

Although, besides that specific question, there are many questions which obviously fit 2 or more close reasons. Just choose the reason you think fits best. If you can't decide which is best since you think 2 or more close reasons fit equally well, then just click on one of those reasons and vote to close and move on.

Some fun info, here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547979/c-string-immutable) that was closed as duplicate to 5 different questions. Thanks to @rene for the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/328481/max-number-of-dupes-on-a-question) that found that question.

Comment: Well that's true!! Moving on is the best option here.. :)

Comment: If a question is closed as duplicate to 5 others, doesn't that mean that those 5 are themselves likely duplicates of each others...

Comment: Tangent, you can use they/their as indefinite third person singular instead of having to do s/he and him/her.

Answer (score 16):

It's basically a perfect fit for:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

"Too broad" would also have been fine. "Unclear" as a third possibility, but it seems to me the "recommend" reason above is exactly applicable.

Comment: Now am confused here to choose best answer.. :) both the answers are good enough.. :) Thank you for your time.. :)